# How to add grid columns to a specific row in WPF .Net Core 3.1 programatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, grid

I'm starting to develop application on WPF, so I'm completely new to the project.Don't like XAML, and want to do everything programmatically so here is the question I got two rows, first one is with Ribbon button and for the second one I want to add columns but only for the second row.

When I add the columns on the second row I get columns on the first one also and I don't want that.

Please act like you don't notice that hardcoded int for row count and column count.

```
public static class GridCustomClass
{
        static GridLength gridLength = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
        static GridLength gridLengthColumns = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
        static GridLength gridLengthColumnsStar = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Star);

        public static void AddFirstGridRows(Grid grid)
        {
            int rowsCount = 2;

            for (int rows = 0; rows < rowsCount; rows++)
            {
                RowDefinition rowDefinition = new RowDefinition();
                rowDefinition.Height = gridLength;
                grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefinition);
            }
        }

        public static Grid AddGridColumnsForLeftPane(Grid grid)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <3; i++)
            {
                ColumnDefinition columnDefinition = new ColumnDefinition();
                switch(i)
                {
                    case 1:
                        columnDefinition.Width = gridLengthColumnsStar;
                        break;
                    default:
                        columnDefinition.Width = gridLengthColumns;
                        break;
                }
                columnDefinition.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
                grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinition);
            }
            return grid;
        }
}

public partial class ApplicationSettings : Window
{
        Grid myGrid = new Grid();
        Ribbon ribbon;
        RibbonTab ribbonTab;
        RibbonGroup ribbonGroup;

        public ApplicationSettings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GridCustomClass.AddFirstGridRows(myGrid);
            GridCustomClass.AddGridColumnsForLeftPane(myGrid);
            ribbon = new Ribbon();
            //Grid.SetRow(GridCustomClass.AddGridColumnsForLeftPane(myGrid), 1);
            Button btn = new Button();
           
            btn.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
            btn.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty,1);

            //Grid.SetRow(btn, 1);

            Grid.SetRow(ribbon, 0);
        
            myGrid.Children.Add(ribbon);
            myGrid.Children.Add(btn);

            settingsWindow.Content = myGrid;
        }
 }
```

I will be very happy if someone shows me where I go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to nest grids. Declare a first grid with only one column and two rows, then add Ribbon in row 0. Add a second grid in row 1 and set the number of columns as you wish